# Python get list of mac addresses and compare them with list from file

Tags: python, mac-address

I am a beginner in Python and I hope you can help me solve this problem.

I have a list of mac addresses written in a file. I need to get the list of mac addresses on the network, compare them with the addresses from the file and then print in stdout the addresses from the file that are not found in the list of addresses from the network.

And in the end update the file with those addresses.

For now I managed to read a file that I give as an argument:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as my_file:
   lines = my_file.read()

my_list = lines.splitlines()
```

I am trying to read the mac addresses by running the process arp from python:

```
import subprocess

addresses = subprocess.check_output(['arp', '-a'])
```

But with this code I get this:

```
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  156.178.1.1           5h-c9-6f-78-g9-91     dynamic
  156.178.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  167.0.0.11            05-00-9b-00-00-10     static
  167.0.0.123           05-00-9b-00-00-ad     static
  .....
```

How can I filter here so I can get only the list of mac addresses?

Or can I check the two lists like this to see if a mac address from the file is on the network and if not to print it out?

Comment: *And in the end update the file with those addresses.* update which file?

Comment: `5h-c9-6f-78-g9-91` this isn't a valid mac address; `g` isn't a hexadecimal digit.

Comment: I know...I modifed it on purpose...it's just an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with what you have:

```
networkAdds = addresses.splitlines()[1:]
networkAdds = set(add.split(None,2)[1] for add in networkAdds if add.strip())
with open(sys.argv[1]) as infile: knownAdds = set(line.strip() for line in infile)

print("These addresses were in the file, but not on the network")
for add in knownAdds - networkAdds:
    print(add)
```

Comment: I am getting an IndexError at line networkAdds = set(add.split(None,2)[1] for add in networkAdds): index out of range.

Comment: @scm: ensure that you have no empty lines in the output from subprocess

Comment: is it a computer setting then? cause I tested it on a different computer where there are no empty lines and it works. how can I ensure there are no empty lines?

Comment: @schmimona: check out the update. That should fix the empty-line issue

Answer (score 1):

To fetch MAC address you can use this regular expression:

```
import re

addresses = """  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
156.178.1.1           5f-c9-6f-78-f9-91     dynamic
156.178.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
167.0.0.11            05-00-9b-00-00-10     static
167.0.0.123           05-00-9b-00-00-ad     static
....."""

print(re.findall(('(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,}(?:\-|\:)){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,}'),addresses))
```

Output:

```
['5f-c9-6f-78-f9-91', 'ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff', '05-00-9b-00-00-10', '05-00-9b-00-00-ad']
```

As far as I can see your MAC-adresses are not following naming convention used in this regexp, so it is up to you to play with `[0-9a-fA-F]` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use **split()** and **count** the amount of **`-`** characters in each item:

```
text = """  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  156.178.1.1           5h-c9-6f-78-g9-91     dynamic
  156.178.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  167.0.0.11            05-00-9b-00-00-10     static
  167.0.0.123           05-00-9b-00-00-ad     static
  ....."""

for item in text.split():
    if item.count('-') == 5:
        print item
```

Output:

```
5h-c9-6f-78-g9-91
ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff
05-00-9b-00-00-10
05-00-9b-00-00-ad
```

You can also do it with **list comprehensions** (listcomps):

```
print [item for item in text.split() if item.count('-') == 5]
```

Output:

```
['5h-c9-6f-78-g9-91', 'ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff', '05-00-9b-00-00-10', '05-00-9b-00-00-ad']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `/proc/net/arp` and avoid the need for a subprocess at all:

```
with open("/proc/net/arp") as f, open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as my_file:
    next(f)
    mac_addrs = {mac for  _, _, _, mac,_, _ in map(str.split, f)}
    for mac in map(str.rstrip, my_file):
        if mac not in mac_addrs:
           print("No entry for addr: {}".format(mac))
```

`/proc/net/arp` looks like:

```
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    0x1         0x2         xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx     *        wlan0
```

where the fourth column is the mac/hw address. If you were to use arp you might also find `arp -an` gives you less output to parse.

If you want to add macs that are listed in the network but not in the file you can open with `"a+"` and append any values not seen to the file at the end:

```
with open("/proc/net/arp") as f, open(sys.argv[1], 'a+') as my_file:
        next(f)
        mac_addrs = {mac for _, _, _, mac,_, _ in map(str.split, f)}
        for mac in map(str.rstrip, my_file):
            if mac not in mac_addrs:
               print("No entry for addr: {}".format(mac))
            else:
                mac_addrs.remove(mac)
        my_file.writelines("{}\n".format(mac)for mac in mac_addrs)
```